# My Windows 10 computer clock is 2 minutes slow. How do I fix it without admin privileges?

Tags: windows, windows-10

[Control Panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BBvlf.png)My school computer clock is slow by 2 minutes. Because of COVID-19, my school is closed, and everything I've tried online you have to have admin rights to do. Any ideas?

Comment: Is Time (Control Panel) set to Internet Time (time.windows.com) or to your school system clock?  Which one?

Comment: https://superuser.com/help/on-topic rules out _...issues specific to corporate IT support and networks,_

Comment: How do you get to the control panel?

Comment: Start and in the search icon type Control Panel

Comment: I just added a link in my question of a screenshot of the control panel. It says "there are no items to display".

Comment: Since you are not an Administrator on the machine, and you do not have access to Control Panel, the problem you describe cannot be solved.  Your clock being 2 minutes slow/fast shouldn't cause any problems.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your input. This is for your school administrator to fix, either in due course when back at school, or by remoting into your computer. There is nothing you can do on your own. Just ignore the time difference until it is fixed by your school.

There is most likely a policy preventing students from using the Control Panel.